# Is there some replacement for 'max' function and grouping (performance optimization of aggregate operations)?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

I have a big query which also returns very big response. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT group, subgroup, max(last_update) FROM
(
    SELECT a as group, a1 as subgroup, d1 as last_update FROM....
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b as group, b1 as subgroup, d2 as last_update FROM....
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c as group, c1 as subgroup, d3 as last_update FROM....
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d as group, d1 as subgroup, d3 as last_update FROM....
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e as group, e1 as subgroup, d4 as last_update FROM....
    ... and some more selects (15 select queries in total)
) GROUP BY group, subgroup;
```

As you can see I need to load maximum date from some groups. The problem is that those dates needs to be loaded from 15 selects and it works very slow (~4s). I tested that subselect

```
SELECT a as group, a1 as subgroup, d1 as last_update FROM....
UNION ALL
SELECT b as group, b1 as subgroup, d2 as last_update FROM....
UNION ALL
SELECT c as group, c1 as subgroup, d3 as last_update FROM....
UNION ALL
SELECT d as group, d1 as subgroup, d3 as last_update FROM....
UNION ALL
SELECT e as group, e1 as subgroup, d4 as last_update FROM....
... ans some more selects
```

works pretty (~0.1s) fast and the problem is with grouping function (thats why query works slowly):

```
SELECT group, subgroup, max(last_update) FROM
(
    ...
) GROUP BY group, subgroup;
```

Is there some way to improve this grouping? As I wrote the goal is to get maximum dates  for each subgroup in group.

Comment: How often do you run this query?

Comment: It will be ran few times a day but it is used in webservices so we want to improve it as most as possible.

Comment: I would like you to change the title of the question, something about "performance optimization of aggregate operations". It would be easy for other people to find your question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer you take a look at parallel queries:

```
create table ttt as
with t(a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1, last_updated) as (
  select 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, sysdate + 1 from dual union all
  select 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, sysdate from dual union all
  select 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, sysdate + 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, sysdate + 1 from dual union all
  select 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, sysdate + 3 from dual union all
  select 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, sysdate + 2 from dual union all
  select 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, sysdate + 4 from dual union all
  select 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, sysdate + 3 from dual 
)
select * from t;

select a grp, a1 subgrp, max(last_updated)
  from ttt
 group by a, a1
```

Explain plan [image: for the first query]

Let's add some parallelism:

```
alter table ttt parallel;

select a grp, a1 subgrp, max(last_updated)
  from ttt
 group by a, a1
```

Explain plan [image: for the second query]

As you can see the cost cut down. But it is not for free, during a parallel query execution the query use all the resources you have, so it could damage your performance, but you said that this query was run not so often, I think this is a good solution. To read more about parallel query take a look at [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Parallel_Query_FAQ)

Comment: Query coordinator overhead makes it difficult for parallelism to help with queries that only run a few seconds.  The cost estimate can be especially bad for parallelism since Oracle assumes linear performance improvement.  I wouldn't bet on parallelism helping a query that already runs in 4 seconds.  Especially since 11g does not have [Concurrent Execution of Union ALL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/parallel003.htm#BEIHEDJJ).

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about UNION ALL for [11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/parallel003.htm), you showed the link related to 12c. To prevent overhead of system resources Oracle 11gR2 has [Parallel Statement Queuing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#BEIBACGC). Furthermore, the creator of the question said that this query would be run only a few times a day.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that feature was only introduced in 12c.  In 11g, each of the 15 select statements may run with parallelism, but they will not run at the same time.  Oracle will probably spend more time dividing up the work and waiting for parallel servers than the actual work itself.  It may not be a huge strain on the system but it may make the query run slower.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I agree, there is not the silver bullet that helps you to improve any performance of any query/system. At least, developers have to try and find out if the parallelism increase the performance of the desired query.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe do the `group by` in each individual subquery too?

```
select g, s, max(last_update) from (
  select g, s, max(last_update) as last_update from t1 group by g, s
  union all
  select g, s, max(last_update) as last_update from t2 group by g, s
  union all
  ...
)
group by g, s
```

I can't say for sure, but if the server is building a temporary rowset for the query then this might cut down the size of that temporary.

Comment: I tried it before but without success. Query still runs too slowly.

Comment: Just a thought you can reduce the number of rows to be processed by the outer query by replacing union all with union ????

Answer (score 0):

That query looks syntactically incorrect to me:

```
SELECT group, subgroup, max(last_update) FROM
(
    SELECT a as group, a1 as subgroup FROM....
```

You do a max on the LAST_UPDATE but it's not included in your subqueries?!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ed Avis answer we can further reduce the number of rows to group by the result set by using UNION instead of UNION ALL

```
select g, s, max(last_update) from (
select g, s, max(last_update) as last_update from t1 group by g, s
union
select g, s, max(last_update) as last_update from t2 group by g, s
union
...
)
group by g, s
```

Comment: Might reduce number of rows by UNION instead of UNION ALL, but probably do more work. UNION works as a UNION ALL followed by a DISTINCT (or GROUP BY), so by using UNION instead of UNION ALL you will introduce *two* grouping operations - first one executed by UNION to reduce the number of rows, and then the second GROUP BY afterwards.