# Best way to execute oracle SQL statements in parallel

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, oracle, parallel-processing

I have asked a similar query before but now I would appreciate specifics. I have 5-11 SQL that need ran in a C# .NET 4.5 web application, currently they are done sequentially, which results in slow response times.

Talking to various architects/DBA they all tell me this can be improved by running the queries in parallel, but never give the specifics of how, when I ask they become very vague ;0)

Is there some function available in Oracle that I could call to pass queries to run in parallel?

Or I have been looking into ASYNC/AWAIT functionality, however the examples on the web are confusing (most involve returning control to the UI, then updating some text on the screen when the task finally completes), I would like to know how to call several methods for them to execute their SQL in parallel and then wait for all of them to complete before proceeding.

If anyone could point me in the direction of good documentation or provide specific examples I would appreciate it!!!!

Updated with sample code, could someone point out how to update this to async to wait for all the various calls to complete:

```
    private CDTInspection GetDetailsInner(CDTInspection tInspection)
    {
        //Call Method one to get data
        tInspection = Method1(tInspection);

        //Call Method two to get data
        Method2(tInspection);

        //Call Method three to get data
        Method3(tInspection);

        //Call Method four to get data
        Method4(tInspection);

        return tInspection;

    }



    private void method2(CDTInspection tInspection)
    {
        //Create the parameter list
        //Execute the query
        //MarshalResults
    }
```

Comment: Easiest way is to have multiple threads (with one Oracle connection each) in your application code.

Comment: See my previous [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74968/44593), another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25261576/3686755)

Comment: Depends on what your architects meant. If they advise you to merge your 5-11 queries into one parallelised query, this can and should be done within the database. If they advise you to run your 5-11 seperate queries in parallel, this should be done in programming language.

Comment: Async/await is about **asynchronuous** programming - that doesn't have anything to do with **executing in parallel** ....

Comment: Actually I think thats the problem, I must have gotten confused with async processing being used for a solution for this issue, there are examples out there where they state multiple long running sql is a reason for using it, but no actual examples. I will look into threading instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can create jobs using **`DBMS_SCHEDULER`** to run independently. Read more from the documentation about [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235).

For example, you could run jobs in parallel as:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg1.proc1', false);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg2.proc2', false);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg3.proc3', false);
END;
/
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some code here, this is a bad idea to give links on other resources only.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO. This answer could well end up in a review queue for deletion if you don't include the key points from those links in your answer.

Comment: Ok, never mind. I will do as suggested. I am new to SO, wasn't aware that links to Oracle documentation won't just suffice. will prepare useful points to post. I am a moderator in other Oracle forums, but this rule/expectation is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run your 5-11 queries in parallel within your application you will have to start multiple threads and execute the queries within the threads in parallel.

However, if you want the database to execute a query in parallel on the database server(s), usually useful if the query is long running and you want to speed up the individual query execution time, then you can use [Parallel Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/parallel.htm#VLDBG010).

Parallel execution benefits systems with all of the following characteristics:

- Symmetric multiprocessors (SMPs), clusters, or massively parallel systems
- Sufficient I/O bandwidth
- Underutilized or intermittently used CPUs (for example, systems where CPU usage is typically less than 30%)
- Sufficient memory to support additional memory-intensive processes, such as sorting, hashing, and I/O buffers

The easiest way to implement parallel execution is via a hint:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable;
```

However, this might not be the best way as it would change your query and has other downsides (like what if you want to deactivate parallelism again, you would have to change the query again). Another way is to specify on table level:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable PARALLEL;
```

That would allow to simply deactivate parallel execution again if it is not wanted anymore without changing the query itself.